# Jquery ajax POST response is null

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a js script that does an ajax request and posts the data to a php script, this script with then echo something back depending if it works or not.

here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var post_data = [];
        $('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
        setInterval(function(){
            post_data = [   {market_number:1, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_1').text().trim()},
                    {market_number:2, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_2').text().trim()}];

            $.ajax({
                        url: 'signals.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data:{markets:post_data},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log("Response was "  + response);
                        },
                        failure: function(result){
                            console.log("FAILED");
                            console.log(result);
                        }
            });
        }, 6000); 
    });
```

here is the php:

```
if(isset($_POST["json"]))
    {
        $json = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
        if(!empty($json))
        {
                echo "IT WORKED!!!!";
        }
            else
                echo "NOT POSTED";
    }
```

So basically, i thought the response in the `success: function(response)' method would be populated with either "IT WORKED!!!" or "NOT POSTED" depending on the if statement in the php. Now everything seem to work because the js script manages to go into the success statement but prints this to the console:

> Response was null

I need to be able to get the return from the server in order to update the screen.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste your `$_POST` array result here? So that every body will find out what you're posting!

Comment: The problem is that i ouput the error sent to the php i get array() an empty array.

Comment: That's why your response from PHP file giving you `null`

Comment: Yeah but why is it not finding the array data? It's seeing a POST but it's not finding the data in the post.

Comment: I just managed to play with it and now my console out put is this: 'Response was Array
(
    [GBPUSD] => undefined
    [EURUSD] => undefined
)'

Comment: and now i can see what i've done wrong. The data is not stored as i want it to be. It should be market => GBPUSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST["markets"]))
{
    $json = json_decode($_POST["markets"]);
    if(!empty($json))
    {
            echo "IT WORKED!!!!";
    }
        else
            echo "NOT POSTED";
}
```

Comment: Nicely spotted. I assumed that the $_POST names were correct. +1!

Answer (score 1):

use this in your php file

```
if(isset($_POST["markets"]))
    {

    }
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST["json"]))
    {
.
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obiously the `if(isset($_POST["json"]))` statement is not invoked, so neither of both echos is executed.
The fact that the function specified in .ajax success is invoked, only tells you that the http connection to the url was successful, it does not indicate  successful processing of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Look, You send data in `market` variable not in json. Please change on single.php code by this.

```
$json_data = array();
if(isset($_POST["markets"]))
{
 //  $json = json_decode($_POST["markets"]);
 $json = ($_POST["markets"]);
 if(!empty($json))
        echo "IT WORKED!!!!";
    else
        echo  "NOT POSTED";
}
```

And change on your ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var post_data = [];
$('.trade_window').load('signals.php?action=init'); 
setInterval(function(){
    post_data = [   {market_number:1, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_1').text().trim()},
            {market_number:2, name:$('.trade_window .market_name_2').text().trim()}];

    $.ajax({
                url: 'signals.php',
                type: 'post',
         //       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data:{markets:post_data},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("Response was "  + response);
                },
                failure: function(result){
                    console.log("FAILED");
                    console.log(result);
                }
    });
},6000);
```

});

Comment: Yeah i just realised I'm not sending JSON data. I have implemented your code but i'm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`

Comment: Ok. let me check on test page.

Comment: Try now, I updated code of ajax call. It will be work for you. I tested this personally on test page. If you have more query let me know... :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that doesn't even trigger the success method for me.... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It seems as if the post data won't go to the php script.

Comment: you seen that i did comment On `contentType`. Do that .. Because of that data not posting on php page. Let  me know what happen or give me your error.

Comment: With the `contentType` gone i don't get anything printed to the console at all.

Comment: look on above link i gave you a link for demo prepared.

Comment: So i should see either "IT WORKED!!!" or "NOT POSTED" in the console when i run your files yea? Because i don't get any console response?

Comment: That was with Chrome, but i check with Firebug and i do get "IT WORKED" back. I think I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: No matter what i do it always comes down to the php not being about to get the post data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "success:" wrong.

Try this instead.

```
$.post("signals.php", { markets: post_data }).done(function(data) {
    /* This will return either "IT WORKED!!!!" or "NOT POSTED" */
    alert("The response is: " + data);
});
```

Also have a look at the jQuery documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I tried using the done method but i keep getting errors with it.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'`

Comment: That indicates that you have an old version of jQuery. You can check your version of jQuery from the console by typing: $().jquery

Answer (score 0):

You have to you change you $.ajax call with

```
   //below post_data array require quotes for keys like 'market_number' and update with your required data
   post_data = [   {'market_number':1, 'name':'name1'},
            {'market_number':2, 'name':'name2'}];
        //console.log(post_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "yourfile.php",
            type:'post',
            async: true,
            data:{'markets':post_data},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
```

and you php file will be

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['markets']))
{
    echo "It worked!!!";
}
else
{
    echo "It doesn't worked!!!";
}
//if you want to work with json then below will help you
//$data = json_encode($_POST['markets']);
//print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still returns undefined! name1 => undefined and so on.

Comment: You also have to put `market_number` into `'market_number'` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

in your php file check the $_POST:

```
echo(json_encode($_POST));
```

which will tell if your data has been posted or not and the data structure in $_POST.

I have used the following code to covert the posted data to associative array:

```
$post_data = json_decode(json_encode($_POST), true);
```